# Implementing an interface if present

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, interface

I'm trying to figure out if something is possible in C#. I'm writing a mod/plugin for Kerbal Space Program, plugins are C# code written and compiled into DLLs. The DLLs are placed in a folder in the KSP directory and KSP loads them during initialization.

I want a class in my plugin to be able to implement an interface in another plugin without a hard dependency. My plugin can be included without the other and the other can be included without mine, but if both are present additional functionality is exposed via the interface.

Effectively, Plugin A exposes one set of functionality, and importantly to this question exposes an interface that it relies on to recognize classes with a particular capability.

Plugin B exposes a different set of functionality, but has compatibility with that interface and would like to implement it.

How do you write these plugins such that neither is a hard dependency for the other, yet Plugin B still utilizes the interface from A in it's classes? My base instinct is that the interface needs to actually be placed in a separate DLL and both plugin A and B become dependent on that DLL which still isn't ideal. I'm also unsure of how these would interact if the said DLL which contains the interface is included, and thus an attempt is made to load it, twice.

Important final note: KSP is written in Unity and is still reliant on .net 3.5, so the additional functionality in 4+ isn't available to me.

Comment: Perhaps you could expose the interface from a different class and have both plugins reference the same interface in that manner? This way they have a common dependency, but there is no direct dependent from one to the other.

Comment: Pulling out the shared interface is an option. Another one is to discover methods using reflection. That is quite brittle though. The shared interface is a better option.

Comment: Common way would be to make one  'shared' lib on which others will depend. If you want to do this differently then try to use Kerbal's API for your own plugins.